# ubuntu 14.04 LTS update openssl manually

Tags: 14.04, python3, openssl

I have created virtual environment by:

```
    python3.6 -m venv myvenv
```

Then I've activated it:

```
    source myvenv/bin/activate
```

After that I wanted to use pip:

```
    pip install requests
```

Then the error has cone up:

```
    pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the 
    ssl module in Python is not available.
    Collecting requests
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: 
    There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect 
    to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests 
    (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for requests
```

As I understand it's something to do with openssl version installed in the system. I've checked the version:

```
    ssh -V
```

That's what I saw:

```
    OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

It's old version but as I get it it's not upgradeable for ubuntu 14.04 lts. Is that right?

Also I have tried to install tar archive from here:

https://www.openssl.org/source/

the last version openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz and it's been installed successfully to the location - /usr/local/openssl

But when I check the version in the system it's still 1.0.1f and I still have the same error in the virtual environment. Maybe I should point out the system to the location where new openssl reside?

Thank you.

Comment: Look here: [Openssh](https://packages.debian.org/pt-br/wheezy/openssh-client). Your ssh version use **libssl1.0.0**. You need to update your ssh to version **>=7.4**. OpenSSL 1.0.0 is different from OpenSSL 1.0.2. They are different packages, so different dependencies.

Comment: i've tried to install from here:

http://www.openssh.com/portable.html

and I've done this with make and make install. But something went wrong I suppose because when I type ssh -v it's still the old version there. Don'y you have a link to the instruction where I can read how to handle this please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue and it's not related to Openssh client. After installation of the openssl-1.0.2n to the system all I needed to do is to recompile Python 3.6.4 and everything then has worked fine. I didn't get the error in my virtual environment anymore and could successfully use PIP for installation of the modules. So this was related to upgrade of Openssl finally.

Thanks.